# How to index an int array via button?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

My code appends ints to an array. There is no sorting. I would like to index every entry to the array. Sort the array from smallest to largest.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var enterText: UITextField!
    var arrayOfInt = [Int]()

    @IBAction func submitText(_ sender: Any) {
        if let text = enterText.text {
            if let number = Int(text) {
                arrayOfInt.append(number)
                print(arrayOfInt)
            } else {
                print("Please enter number")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
@IBAction func submitText(_ sender: Any) {
    if let text = enterText.text {
        if let number = Int(text) {
            var index = 0
            for num in arrayOfInt {
                if num > number {
                    arrayOfInt.insert(number, at: index)
                    break
                }
                index += 1
            }
            print(arrayOfInt)
        } else {
            print("Please enter number")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. Don't you have to define index? I am just trying to automatically sort each entry of the arrayOfInt atomically. Each time a new entry is added. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add. You have to add ‘var index =0’ before for loop.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: This compiles its just when print(arrayOfInt) is printed nothing appears. Just []. Thats it.